# Insert row and adopt the formula above (from protected cell)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel-sheet with a table defined. In this table there are simple calculations for a bill (amount * price = total). The total-cell with this formula is *protected*.

When I protect the whole worksheet I allow the users to insert rows (so the user can insert new positions to the bill). But when the total-cell is protected, the formula behind this cell is not adopted in the newly inserted cell (without protection, everything works fine).

I know, I can handle this with macro/vba. But this is not an option. Is there another way to achive this? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You protect a cell to prevent it from being edited; now you want to edit the protected cell. Do you absolutely need to protect the sheet?